# Usar Base de Dados Existente com Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Tô precisando de uma ajuda para saber se existe uma forma de usar uma base de dados existente com Entity Framework sem ter que usar a importação do Visual Studio, e sem usar o *Database First* pois não quero amarrar meu código, porque acho que dessa forma fica mais difícil de dar manutenção.

Gostaria de alguma forma usar a base de dados que já tenho e usá-la com o Entity Framework.

Comment: Vai de Fluent NHibernate

Answer (score 4):

Possível, é, mas é preciso atentar para algumas coisas:

## 1. Você precisa ter algum domínio mapeado

Quando me refiro a domínio, me refiro ao seu sistema ter uma classe para cada coleção (ou tabela) que o seu sistema usa, sendo que cada objeto represente um registro da sua coleção (ou tabela).

## 2. Você precisará indicar seguir uma nomenclatura, ou então usar de atributos de decoração para fazer o Entity Framework entender o seu domínio

O Entity Framework entende um objeto de domínio que esteja na seguinte forma:

```
public class MeuObjeto
{
    public int MeuObjetoId { get; set; }
}
```

Ele entende que `MeuObjetoId` é chave primária de uma coleção (ou tabela) chamada `MeuObjeto`.

Ou então:

```
public class MeuObjeto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Ou ainda:

```
public class MeuObjeto
{
    [Key]
    public int MinhaColunaDeIdPersonalizada { get; set; }
}
```

`[Key]` indica qual propriedade será tratada como chave primária.

## 3. Você precisará informar como é o relacionamento entre suas entidades

Basicamente são 3:

- 1 pra 1;
- 1 pra N;
- N pra N.

### 1 pra 1

```
public class MeuObjeto
{
    [Key]
    public int MeuObjetoId { get; set; }
    public int OutroObjetoId { get; set; }

    public virtual OutroObjeto OutroObjeto { get; set; }
}
```

### 1 pra N

```
public class MeuObjeto
{
    [Key]
    public int MeuObjetoId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MeuObjetoDetalhe> MeuObjetoDetalhes { get; set; }
}
```

### N pra N

```
public class MeuObjeto
{
    [Key]
    public int MeuObjetoId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AssociacaoObjeto> AssociacaoObjetos { get; set; }
}

public class OutroObjeto
{
    [Key]
    public int OutroObjetoId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AssociacaoObjeto> AssociacaoObjetos { get; set; }
}

public class AssociacaoObjeto
{
    [Key]
    public int AssociacaoObjetoId { get; set; }
    public int OutroObjetoId { get; set; }
    public int MeuObjetoId { get; set; }

    public virtual MeuObjeto MeuObjeto { get; set; }
    public virtual OutroObjeto OutroObjeto { get; set; }
}
```